# android api portability error

Tags: android, android-mapview, portability

I have a little problem. I have created an android api that uses google maps(mapview) on my pc with eclipse and the android emulator. Everything seems to be running fine on my pc, but when I try to install and run the same api on my laptop everything runs great, except that when I navigate to the activity using the mapView, the map shows grey with grids on the screen and not as a map. Could the problem be, that because I am running the api on a different pc, I should create a new api key to use? In another topic, I have seen that a possible solution could be, to change the version of the java compiler to the one that the program was originally compiled. I tried this too to no effect. Any help would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Maps API key corresponds to your app key, when running the app locally without signing it with a keystore the app is signed by the eclipse debug key (which is different for every computer), so you need to create a new API key for every debug keystore you're using. To sum it up, you need a different API key for each development computer and off-course another API key for your release keystore.

Answer (score 1):

You need to share the debug.keystore between machines for the map to show on different machines while development.

For that in Eclipse, go to Preferences -> Android -> Build and set the Custom debug keystore appropriately which u are using on your pc to view Google Maps.

Or else create a different API key for each development computer.

You will have to create a separate keystore for the release of the app.